# Python3 print selected values of dict

Tags: python-3.x

In this simple code to read a tsv file of many columes:

```
InColnames = ['Chr','Pos','Ref','Alt']
tsvin = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter='\t')
for row in tsvin:
    print(', '.join(row[InColnames]))
```

How can I make the print work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do:

```
for row in tsvin:
    print(', '.join(row[col] for col in InCOlNames))
```

You cannot pass a list of keys to the `dict`'s item-lookup and magically get a list of values. You have to somehow iterate the keys and retrieve each one's value individually. The approach at hand uses a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) for that.